# what is the difference between event listerners and subscribers in symfony2

Tags: events, symfony, doctrine

I am getting confused with event subscribers.

I understand that  Event listener wait for something to happen and if that condition happens then they execute the function.

But what does event subscriber do.

Can someone please explain in laymans language with general example